# Regex to select text based on angle brackets having nested angle brackets

Tags: java, regex

I wanted to select text based on below scenarios. I tried couple of regex but still I am not able to cover all the scenarios using one regex.

**Set 1**

`<x> <y>`  Result should be two groups **<x>** and **<y>**

`<Name> <NewName>` Result should be two groups **<Name>** and **<NewName>**

**Set 2**

`sampletext <!PARSE<sampletext>><.value>` Result should be two groups **sampletext** and **<!PARSE<sampletext>><.value>**

`found <!PARSE<XYZ.ID>notfound>` Result should be two groups **<found>** and **<!PARSE<XYZ.ID>notfound>**

`<XYZ.IDXX> notfound` Result should be two groups **<XYZ.IDXX>** and **notfound**

`notFoundString <!PARSE<XYZ.IDXX>notfound>` Result should be two groups **<notFoundString>** and **<!PARSE<XYZ.IDXX>notfound>**

`notFoundEmpty <!PARSE<XYZ.IDXX>>` Result should be two groups **<notFoundEmpty>** and **<!PARSE<XYZ.IDXX>>**

**Set 3**

`<thread.end> <thread.start>` Result should be two groups **<thread.end>** and **<thread.start>**

`<!MINUS <thread.end> <thread.start>> 1000` Result should be two groups **<!MINUS <thread.end> <thread.start>>** and **1000**

`thread.duration <!DIVISION <!MINUS <thread.end> <thread.start>> 1000>` Result should be two groups **thread.duration** and **<!DIVISION <!MINUS <thread.end> <thread.start>> 1000>**

**Set 4**

`1234 5678` Result should be two groups **1234** and **5678**

`add.sample.result <!ADD 1234 5678>` Result should be two groups **add.sample.result** and **<NewName>**

**Regexs I tried**

1. `<([^>]*)>|(\S+)` This works fine in Set 1 and 4, but in Set 2 and 3, it captures more groups than required. https://regexr.com/3si0v
2. `<(.*)>|(\S+)`  This works fine for Set 2 and 4, but gives wrong results in Set 1 and 3. https://regexr.com/3si12

I need regex which give expected results as mentioned above in all sets.

Comment: The [`((?:<(?:[^<>]*(?:<[^<>]*(?:<[^<>]*>[^<>]*)*>[^<>]*)*)>)+)|(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/KepvgI/3) will work for the nested angle brackets two levels deep.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. This seems to be working perfectly. It will be helpful if you can comment about the working of this. It looks bit complex. or Can it be more simplified?

Comment: Are you asking if it can be simplified for a human being or a machine? I always try to optimize for best performance.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew for human being. or may be if you can elaborate about working of this for me to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
((?:<[^<>]*(?:<[^<>]*(?:<[^<>]*>[^<>]*)*>[^<>]*)*>)+)|(\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KepvgI/3)

It either matches and captures into 2 groups `(?:<[^<>]*(?:<[^<>]*(?:<[^<>]*>[^<>]*)*>[^<>]*)*>)+` or `\S+` patterns.

**Details**

- `(?:<[^<>]*(?:<[^<>]*(?:<[^<>]*>[^<>]*)*>[^<>]*)*>)+` - matches 1 or more consecutive occurrences of

  - `<` - a `<`
  - `[^<>]*` - 0+ chars other than `<` and `>`
  - `(?:<[^<>]*(?:<[^<>]*>[^<>]*)*>[^<>]*)*` - 0+ sequences of

    - `<[^<>]*(?:<[^<>]*>[^<>]*)*>` - Nested level 1:
    - `<[^<>]*` - `<` and 0+ chars other than `<` and `>`
    - `(?:<[^<>]*>[^<>]*)*`  - Nested level 2: 0+ sequences of

      - `<` - a `<`
      - `[^<>]*` - 0+ chars other than `<` and `>`
      - `>` - a `>`
      - `[^<>]*` - 0+ chars other than `<` and `>`
    - `>`  - a `>` char
    - `[^<>]*` - 0+ chars other than `<` and `>`
  - `>` - a `>`
- `|` - or
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars.